# Creating a Button to Function Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to attach a piece of code to a button OnClick attribute.

```
// Creating a Button
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");

// Append a text to the button

var t = document.createTextNode("random text");
btn.appendChild(t);

// attach the function to the eventLisenter 
btn.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

// function to be executed
var handleClick = function (event) {
    alert("DBZ");
}
```

The button appears where it belongs, and so does the text in it, however when I press the button the code inside the function won't execute, nothing happens.
I have tried running the code in Firefox & Google Chrome.

I have also tried to change the "click" attribute to "onclick" attribute, add/remove bracket of function when attaching and also use the btn.attachNow method. nothing happend really.

Would appreciate any help,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you adding the button the document?

Comment: See this: [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](http://stackoverflow.com/q/336859/4642212).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using a function expression to define your function, and you are doing it **after** you try to assign your event handler.

Consequently, `btn.addEventListener('click', handleClick);` is the same as `btn.addEventListener('click', undefined);`

Move the function definition up your code so it happens first.

Better yet, use a function *declaration* instead of a function expression.

```
function handleClick (event) {
    alert("DBZ");
}
```

Then it will be hoisted and have a useful name when viewed in a debugger.

Comment: great input, I haven't noticed I actually declare a variable therefore i was trying to access an undefined variable, however, why is the function declaration better then then variable declaration that holds a function? is that just sparing the use a pointer to a function?

Comment: Because (a) it is hoisted and (b) it will have a useful name when viewed in a debugger